# Android: How to position 2 fragments with relative width and minimum width?

Tags: android, android-fragments, position

I have 2 fragments, one should have 40% of the displays width, the other one 60%, but the first one should have a minimum width of say 300dp.

I can use "android:layout_weight" to position the fragments relative, but I don't find a way to set a minimum width (in case the 40% width is less than 300dp), neither per Xml nor programmatically.

Comment: The closest I think would be like this:  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="400dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: With these settings the left fragments uses the whole whidth, the right one becomes invisible. Using android:layout_weight="0.4" and android:layout_weight="0.6" I get the correct relations, but then android:layout_width has to be 0, and then android:minWidth does not work.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: I solved your problem (checked in Android Studio).
Lets look into that

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:text="scaled"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The button with 'scaled' caption will never be smaller than 100dp by width.
Just need 2 things:
 1. That button has `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
 2. All other elements in LinearLayout should have `android:layout_width="0dp"`

In that case all other elements width will be controlled by weight. And 'scaled' button too - but it could be smaller that 100dp

Comment: This is exactly why I would like to use minWidth. The left fragment needs a minimum size to display correctly.

Comment: Just checked and solved. I updated my answer.
Pardon me - I did not understand you without computer :) :) :)
Is that what you needed?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this does not seem to work with Fragments instead of Buttons, at least not in my case. But I found a different solution, see below.

Comment: Very strange. Maybe your fragment layout has code driving size?
In any case not a good idea to modify view by code - that may add artefacts and blinking size changes to display.
Better to get layouts of your fragments to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a programmatical solution: With "postDelayed" I wait until the app is completely drawn, I then check with getView().getWidth() if the width is too small and change it with getView().setLayoutParams, so that it redraws the app.